# z-index on a UL LI dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I need some help with putting a z-index in a dropdown menu. I need to give the drop down itself an z-index of at least 10, so that it will be on top of every other images in the menu bar. But so far i've tried everything with positions and z-index, but nothing works.

here is my code so far

```
<ul id="cssdropdown">

    <li class="headlink">
        <a href="http://google.com/">HOME</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://live.com/">Live Search</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

```
 #cssdropdown, #cssdropdown ul {
    list-style: none;
}

    #cssdropdown, #cssdropdown * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

    /* Head links */
#cssdropdown li.headlink {
    width: 120px;
    height:70px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
#cssdropdown li.headlink a {
    display: block;
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size:30px; 
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}

    /* Child lists and links */
#cssdropdown li.headlink ul {
    display: none;
    border-top: 1px black solid;
    text-align: left;
}
#cssdropdown li.headlink:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#cssdropdown li.headlink ul li a {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 17px;
    font-size:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#cssdropdown li.headlink ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}

    /* Pretty styling */
#cssdropdown a {
    color: white;
}
#cssdropdown ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#cssdropdown li.headlink {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
#cssdropdown li.headlink ul {
    background-color: rgb(51,51,51);
    background-position: bottom;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

does someone knows what I am doing wrong in this code?

Thanks!

Comment: Throw up a fiddle so that we can see what you are talking about, and it would likely get more responses... http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: We have to see the full code to get what you mean my friend

Comment: Well, for one thing, you don't have a z-index listed anywhere in that code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J4s3F/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `position:relative` to parent `li` and `position:absolute` to the child `ul`. Now add the `z-index` to the `ul`.

```
#cssdropdown li.headlink{
  position:relative;
}

#cssdropdown li.headlink ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  z-index:10;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/rqjc4/)

Comment: That is the weird part, it doesn't work. I have like a menu bar with inside al these headlinks, onder this menubar i have a 10px height bar with an repeating image inside for decoration. This 10px bar is fixed with an z-index of 5 but the dropdown will allways end up under this bar :/

Comment: i have made it into a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qfhC7/ You see how the div with class 'headerRand' is always on top of the drop down?

Comment: Try giving a `z-index:2` to `.headerRand`

Comment: It's working now, i was affraid 2 wasn't high enough to be on top of social api's and google adsense, but it is! Thanks for the help